# How to show a list of elements from an object in a select using vue and vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

In my project I'm trying to show a street list for the users, then an other select must show the numbers of the selected street. The problem is the format of the data. I have list of object that countains street name, number and letter, so the user must select the street name, then see some numbers and then select the letter. The format of the object list is something like this:

```js
listObject = [{
"street": "first",
"number": 2,
"letter": "A"
},
{
"street": "second",
"number": 1,
"letter": "B"
},
{
"street": "second",
"number": 3,
"letter": "C"
},
{
"street": "second",
"number": 3,
"letter": "A"
},
{
"street": "first",
"number": 2,
"letter": "B"
},
{
"street": "second",
"number": 4,
"letter": "A"
}]
```

Vuetify uses the v-select component that lets you put a list of elements in the select, but I don't know how to use it with my object, I have thought about a computed property to separate in diferent list the diferent object properties but havent success. I know there must be an easier way to do it, but I cant not figure it out how to separate the data and keeps the data integrity. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props

You should look for props:

- `return-object` to return value as object
- `item-text` to format item on selectlist

```
<v-select 
  :items="listObject"
  return-object
  :item-text="item => `${item.street} ${item.number} ${item.letter}`"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the `item-text` and `item-value` to customize the select :

```
<v-select
          :items="listObject "
           item-text="street"
           item-value="number"
        ></v-select>
```